# How can I configure a Gradle plugin externally to the build?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

How can I apply a plugin configuration to a Gradle project externally of the build so that it does not get included in Git source control?

### Details

I have a Gradle project which uses the [gradle-git-properties](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties) plugin to generate a `git.properties` file based on the project's Git details.

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties'
}

// Rest of build.gradle goes here
```

Additionally, I'm checking out my project to multiple locations locally using [git working trees](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree).  However, projects using gradle-git-properties fail when run from a linked working tree, per [gradle-git-properties#14](https://github.com/n0mer/gradle-git-properties/issues/14).

```
$ ./gradlew generateGitProperties
> Task :subproject:generateGitProperties FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':subproject:generateGitProperties'.
> Error while evaluating property 'generatedProperties' of task ':subproject:generateGitProperties'
   > gradlegitproperties.org.eclipse.jgit.errors.RepositoryNotFoundException: repository not found: /Users/Me/my-project/.git/worktrees/my-project
```

I have been using a plugin configuration to work around the issue, allowing the project to build successfully when run from the linked working tree:

```groovy
gitProperties {
  Path dotGitPath = rootProject.layout.projectDirectory.asFile.toPath().resolve(".git")
  if (Files.isRegularFile(dotGitPath)) {
    Files.lines(dotGitPath).withCloseable { ditGitFileLines ->
      dotGitDirectory = ditGitFileLines
          .filter { it.startsWith("gitdir: ") }
          .map { it.substring('gitdir: '.length(), it.lastIndexOf('/.git/')) }
          .map { project.objects.directoryProperty().convention(project.layout.projectDirectory.dir(it)) }
          .findFirst()
          .orElse(project.objects.directoryProperty().convention(project.layout.projectDirectory.dir(".git")))
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with this solution is that it requires modifying the build file.  This is a shared repository, and I'm the only person accessing it who uses multiple git working trees.  Therefore, I don't want to include this workaround in the build itself.

Is there a way I can automatically apply this plugin configuration externally to the build file or any other file that would be committed with the project?

Answer (score 0):

A Gradle [initialization script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html) can be used, putting the plugin configuration into an external file.

> There are several ways to use an init script:
>
> - Specify a file on the command line. The command line option is `-I` or `--init-script` followed by the path to the script. […]
> - Put a file called `init.gradle` (or `init.gradle.kts` for Kotlin) in the `USER_HOME/.gradle/` directory.
> - Put a file that ends with `.gradle` (or `.init.gradle.kts` for Kotlin) in the `USER_HOME/.gradle/init.d/` directory.
> - Put a file that ends with `.gradle` (or `.init.gradle.kts` for Kotlin) in the `GRADLE_HOME/init.d/` directory, in the Gradle distribution.  […]

**`~/.gradle/init.d/git-worktree-fix.gradle`**

```groovy
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Path

allprojects {
  plugins.withId('com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties') {
    gitProperties {
      Path dotGitPath = rootProject.layout.projectDirectory.asFile.toPath().resolve(".git")
      if (Files.isRegularFile(dotGitPath)) {
        Files.lines(dotGitPath).withCloseable { ditGitFileLines ->
          dotGitDirectory = ditGitFileLines
              .filter { it.startsWith("gitdir: ") }
              .map { it.substring('gitdir: '.length(), it.lastIndexOf('/.git/')) }
              .map { project.objects.directoryProperty().convention(project.layout.projectDirectory.dir(it)) }
              .findFirst()
              .orElse(project.objects.directoryProperty().convention(project.layout.projectDirectory.dir(".git")))
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `gitProperties` configuration is wrapped in a `plugins.withId('com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties')` check, since otherwise projects not using the gradle-git-properties plugin would fail when using this script.